# Different MinGW-w64 version breaks DLL loading

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I have an open-source game project that was mostly developed under Ubuntu. Recently I ported it to Windows, what consisted only in minor tweaks and then building it for Windows, since I only used cross-platform libraries and features.

To build it, initially I cross-compiled using MinGW-w64 from Ubuntu's 19.04 repositories, and it worked like a charm. This is what it reports as the version:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix (GCC) 9.2-posix 20191008
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I updated to Ubuntu 20.04, MinGW-w64 got a small bump in version number:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix (GCC) 9.3-posix 20200320
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The update broke my build, as the executable generated by the new version of MinGW-w64 does not work. When executed on a Windows machine, it is unable to find the symbols from its DLL dependencies, and I get the following popup error:

[image: Entry point not found]

Which should translate to English version of the error message as (filling the variables):

> glome.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>
> The procedure entry point ogg_page_bos could not be located in the dynamic link library «path to glome.exe».

The interesting points to notice here are:

- it is regarding glome.exe as a DLL, different from all the instances of the error I find online, where it puts the executable on the title, but an actual DLL in the body of the message;
- the needed symbol can be found on the companion file libogg-0.dll;
- if I run it on Linux with Wine, it works;
- if I swap the binary glome.exe with the one built in Ubuntu 19.10, it works;
- both builds (Ubuntu 19.10 and Ubuntu 20.04) uses exactly the same compiler arguments, generated by CMake.

This is the command line for the compilation of one of the files of the game (there are many files, but all are compiled in the same way):

```
cd /home/lucas/glome/ubuntu-20.04-win-build/src/sdl && /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix   @CMakeFiles/glome.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -march=haswell -mtune=generic -Ofast -fno-fat-lto-objects -flto=12 -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/opusfile/include/opus/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/opus/include/opus/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/libogg/include/ogg/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/glew-2.1.0/include/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/OpenAL-1.1-SDK/include -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/libogg/include -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/SDL2-2.0.12/include/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/boost_1_72_0/ -g   -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/glome.dir/input.cpp.obj -c /home/lucas/glome/src/src/sdl/input.cpp
```

where `CMakeFiles/glome.dir/includes_CXX.rsp` contains only `-I` directives:

```
-I/home/lucas/glome/src/src/common/. -I/home/lucas/glome/src/external/concurrentqueue -I/home/lucas/glome/ubuntu-20.04-win-build/src -I/home/lucas/glome/src/src/sdl
```

The linking command for the executable is:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix -march=haswell -mtune=generic -Ofast -fno-fat-lto-objects -flto=12 -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/opusfile/include/opus/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/opus/include/opus/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/libogg/include/ogg/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/glew-2.1.0/include/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/OpenAL-1.1-SDK/include -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/libogg/include -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/SDL2-2.0.12/include/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/boost_1_72_0/ -g   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/glome.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o glome.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libglome.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles/glome.dir/linklibs.rsp
```

where `CMakeFiles/glome.dir/linklibs.rsp` contains:

```
../common/libcommon.a -lopengl32 -lglu32 -march=haswell -mtune=generic -Ofast -fno-fat-lto-objects -flto=12 -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/opusfile/include/opus/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/opus/include/opus/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/libogg/include/ogg/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/glew-2.1.0/include/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/OpenAL-1.1-SDK/include -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/libogg/include -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/SDL2-2.0.12/include/ -I/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/boost_1_72_0/ /home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/OpenAL-1.1-SDK/libs/Win64/OpenAL32.lib /home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/glew-2.1.0/lib/Release/x64/glew32.lib /home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/opusfile/lib/libopusfile.a /home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/opus/lib/libopus.dll.a /home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/libogg/lib/libogg.dll.a -L/home/lucas/glome/windows-deps/SDL2-2.0.12/lib/x64/ -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-allow-multiple-definition -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

Apart from the paths (`ubuntu-20.04-win-build` vs `ubuntu-19.10-win-build`), the compilation and linking commands are exactly the same, generated with the same parameters from the same `CMakeLists.txt`.

The questions:

- Why Ubuntu 20.04 build works on Wine but doesn't work on Windows, while Ubuntu 19.10 build works on both?
- How to fix Ubuntu 20.04 build to work on Windows?

Comment: Did you try to compile with MSVC (microsoft's compiler)?

Comment: It took some more porting (because it lacks GNU getopt), but yes, another developer managed to build it in Visual Studio. It works, similar to MinGW-w64 9.2. But what is the relevance?

Comment: MingGW has some bugs as it is based in GCC and GCC is intended to run on Unix-like systems, not on Windows.

Comment: @Ivella getopt (from http://software.frodo.looijaard.name/getopt/download.php) builds with MinGW-w64. You should build that and use it.

Comment: @AkibAzmain GCC is a very general compiler targetting many platforms and MinGW-w64 GCC is a very solid compiler, which generates native Windows executables.

Comment: @BrechtSanders that looks like the command line tool, not the library with the GNU function `getopt_long()`.

Comment: @lvella it's in there, in header file gnu/getopt.h (see: http://svn.frodo.looijaard.name/viewvc/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/public/getopt/trunk/gnu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hanging out in mingw-w64 IRC channel, people there suggested me to open the executable in dependency tracker, which highlighted a big difference between the working and broken binaries: it looks like symbol requirements "leaked" from one DLL into another, unrelated, DLL.

[image: side-by-side dependency walking]

What led people there to take a closer look into the DLL import libraries. In particular, I was linking against some DLLs via their MSVC generated import libraries, namely: `glew32.lib`, `OpenAL32.lib` and `SDL2.lib`.

It seems GNU `ld` has trouble handling import libraries from MSVC, and the fix was simply linking against the DLL files directly, in which case the symbol loading code is generated by `ld` itself (and this is actually a much better supported operation: always link against the .dll directly if possible, import libraries are not needed in GNU toolchain).

I don't know why it worked before, apparently there was a regression in GNU `ld` across the versions I used.

Comment: Tip: I always set up my MSYS2 shell to put the MinGW-w64 stuff first in search paths environment variables like `PATH`, `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` (this last one might have saved you from this issue).

Comment: I wasn't using MSYS32 shell, I was cross compiling from Linux. I downloaded the precompiled libraries from the web and manually specified their paths.

Comment: Don't link MinGW with MSVC libraries. That often leads to crashes. For example when when MSVC malloc() is used to return something from a library function and MSVC free() is used to clean it up. Better is to have everything build by the same compiler.